# "black ice" vs. "glare ice" vs. "glaze" in NAmEng

Tags: american-english, word-usage, dialects, north-american-english, vernacular

What's the difference between those varieties of ice forming on paved surfaces during the cold season?

**black ice**

> sometimes called [clear ice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_ice): a thin, nearly invisible coating of ice that forms on paved surfaces. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/black-ice)

**glare ice**

> : a thin coating of ice (as from freezing mist) on a road or sidewalk; nearly invisible but very hazardous [Memidex](http://www.memidex.com/glare-ice)

**glare**

> *n* A sheet or surface of glassy and very slippery ice. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/black-ice)
>
> *adj* (*US and Canadian*) smooth and glassy: *glare ice*. [CED](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glare)

**glaze**

> : a thin glassy coating of ice. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glaze)
>
> : a smooth slippery coating of thin ice [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glaze)
>
> : (*US*: ice) [verglas](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/verglas)
> (Collins-Robert French and English Dictionary, Ed. 1985)

Comment: They’re all the same and it just depends on which qualities of the ice you wish to emphasize which one you use. Although I’d only use “black ice” if the road surface underneath was black thus causing the ice to look black.

Comment: *[Clear ice](http://www.oregon.gov/odot/comm/pages/winterdriving.aspx)* is another alternative. But *black ice* is about ten times more popular than *glare ice*, and *glaze* can refer to any thin coating of ice, not just the layer that forms on road and sidewalk surfaces.

Comment: @Jim Thing is, black ice, clear ice, glare ice, glaze are all called the same thing out here: verglas; hence my wondering if there's some kind of differences between those terms...https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verglas

Comment: @MacRat "sleet" is another one: "A thin icy coating that forms when rain or sleet freezes, as on trees or streets.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sleet

Comment: I've always (here in Minnesota) distinguished between "black ice" and "glare ice" in that "glare ice" is easily discerned from the shiny surface it has, while "black ice" is almost invisible (and gives the roadway a black appearance in the headlights).  (Of course, a lot depends on lighting conditions.)

Comment: @HotLicks How about "sleet" and "glaze"? Is the thin layer of ice that forms on wintery Minnesotan road and sidewalk surfaces sometimes called by those names?

Comment: @Elian - Around here "sleet" is a form of precipitation -- freezing rain.  It may "glaze" the roads, though (roughly the same as "glare ice", only perhaps not as shiny).

Comment: I second @HotLicks on sleet.  It’s sleet when it’s falling from the sky. It’s granular snow on the ground or maybe slush depending on how cold it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences between black, glare and glaze ice *on paved surfaces* are colloquial, regional and attributive. The terms are often used interchangably, and the sense of each overlaps with the others. So, without accounting for regionalism and localism, the distinctions I know from personal experience with the use of the terms in cold climates are these:

> **black ice** on paved surfaces may or may not appear black. It is effectively invisible while traveling, even at pedestrian speeds, but the term is applied when water freezes on a paved surface in such a way as to compromise traction. I first encountered the term **black ice** used with this sense in Washington State (> 1990). In my prior experience with the term **black ice** in Minnesota (1970-1990), it was applied exclusively to lake ice frozen without many air bubbles. In that case, the ice appears black. With that reference, such ice was highly prized by ice skaters and ice boaters, for its smooth surface and transparency, and by others for its outstanding scenic properties.
>
> **glare** and **glaze** ice on paved surfaces, unlike black ice, reflects light, as suggested by the names, and so is sometimes visible. The two terms are used interchangably, but my observations indicate that **glare** is sometimes used to distinguish a thinner ice layer from the thicker layer formed by **glaze** ice. These observations are supported by my observations of the use of **glaze** ice in, for example, Oklahoma (< 1970), to describe the coating of surfaces and structures, including the twigs and branches of trees and shrubs, etc., with a layer of ice more than one quarter inch thick. While **glare** ice might be used with the same reference, the use of **glaze** as the descriptor was more common.

As mentioned, with reference to ice on pavement, **black**, **glare** and **glaze** are often used interchangably by individual speakers in all regions where I've encountered the terms. With reference to ice on surfaces other than pavement, the choice of term is more likely to be specific to the most notable attribute of the ice, that is, whether it appears black, reflects glare, or glazes surfaces and structures.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Minnesota the most significant term of the above is "black ice".  This term describes what you get when a thin layer of ice coats a relatively smooth asphalt or concrete roadway, so thin that the ice doesn't quite fill in all the voids in the paving material.  That is, there are still some bits of paving material projecting above the ice.

One might think that so long as there is SOME paving material projecting above the ice surface then the ice would not be a problem, but this is not the case.  The surface may *seem* sound from a traction standpoint, but as soon as one makes, say, a slight directional adjustment to center the car in the lane traction may suddenly be lost, sending the car into a violent skid.

The problem with "black ice" is that it's so deceptive.  Because the ice is down inside the little indentations of the road surface it behaves in a way that very little light from the headlights can be reflected back to the driver -- the roadway appears black, as if it were simply wet.  You also don't get, eg, the glare from the headlights of the car ahead that you would get from "glare" ice.  And, because there is SOME traction, it's easy to become over-confident and drive at a speed that is inappropriate for the actual roadway conditions.

Answer (score 1):

My husband uses "glare ice" but I thought he made it up because I've never heard anyone else refer to it this way.  I would say a glaze of ice, personally.  A lot of news media use black ice.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note, however, that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and all answers should address the main question posed in the original post. There is nothing wrong with sharing an anecdotes in and of itself, but it should serve to support a larger argument about usage. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.